# Selenium WebDriver get border color

Tags: java, css, extjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hi all i am trying to get border color of an extjs 4.2 form control text field using getCssValue method. But i am not able to fetch it. it is returning me blank. Below is my code snippet u can try this as is.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class TestClass 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        driver.get("http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/extjs-build/examples/form/dynamic.html");
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@name='first']"));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        element.sendKeys("");
        element.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("'"+element.getCssValue("border-color")+"'");
    }
}
```

[image: Field, Xpath and CSS attribute highlighted in black border]

Webdriver version 2.33 (Java binding)

FF 22

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]
How to get border color or other css values look in **Computed** there are all values that you can get:

```
getCssValue("border-bottom-color")
```

returns rgba(209, 219, 223, 1) and need to clear it (this will work for rgba and rgb):

```
String rgb[] = driver.findElement(By.name("login[email]")).getCssValue("border-bottom-color").replaceAll("(rgba)|(rgb)|(\\()|(\\s)|(\\))","").split(",");
```

Now our rgb is in array using this method to parse it

```
String hex = String.format("#%s%s%s", toBrowserHexValue(Integer.parseInt(rgb[0])), toBrowserHexValue(Integer.parseInt(rgb[1])), toBrowserHexValue(Integer.parseInt(rgb[2])));

private static String toBrowserHexValue(int number) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(Integer.toHexString(number & 0xff));
        while (builder.length() < 2) {
            builder.append("0");
        }
        return builder.toString().toUpperCase();
    }
```

From this **rgba(209, 219, 223, 1)** we got this **#D1DBDF**

P.S. [Source of parsing int rgb to hex](http://sny.no/2011/11/java-hex.html)

Comment: Thanks @Andrian. But can i know why we are not able to get the original border-color property just for my knowledge?

Comment: Here is your answer: http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getCssValue(java.lang.String)
I don't know why they chose to return rgb, but they chose this standard.

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be an issue with element.getCssValue("border-color") using a Firefox Driver. This is due to Shorthand CSS properties (e.g. margin, background, border) not been supported.

For **Firefox** you will need to enter

```
System.out.println("'"+element.getCssValue("border-top-color")+"'");
```

The code will print out **'rgba(207, 76, 53, 1)'**

Using a **ChromeDriver** to get your value.

Your current code will print out **'rgb(207, 76, 53)'**

To set the ChromeDriver you might need to add this line before you declare your driver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

You can download the ChromeDriver from here http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html

Comment: hi Lt_Shade we are not even considering chrome for testing. so i cannot accept this answer. if u have ne workarounds for firefox then do let me know. TIA!!