# Assert style of css for table border using Selenium with Eclipse (Java)

Tags: java, css, selenium, assert

I'm testing a form and part of the test is leaving mandatory fields blank and checking that the field gets a red border indicating that the field is mandatory and should be filled before proceeding is possible. I've got the following code so far:

```
driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();

/** Test: Open page*/
driver.get ("URL with form");

/** the following confirms a text above the form stating what fields are mandatory and not filled */
driver.findElement(By.id("nextbutton")).click(); /** leave all fields blank and click on next below form */
assertEquals("The following fields are mandatory", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("p")).getText());
assertEquals("Field 1 is mandatory", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='genericform']/div[2]/ul/li")).getText());
assertEquals("Field 2 is mandatory", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='genericform']/div[2]/ul/li[2]")).getText());
assertEquals("Field 3 is mandatory", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='genericform']/div[2]/ul/li[3]")).getText());

assertTrue(isElementPresent(By.id("Field1.Value"))); /** confirms the first mandatory field is present */
```

Now I want to confirm/assert that the mandatory field has a red border and an icon where the none-mandatory fields do not have a red border or icon.
[image]

CSS:
  border-color: #E04228;
  background: #FFF url("../img/icon-field-error.png") no-repeat scroll right center / 28px 22px;

I'm using Eclipse with Selenium webdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getCssValue()`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getCssValue(java.lang.String)) method to get `border-bottom-color`, `border-top-color`, `border-left-color` and `border-right-color` CSS properties:

```
assertEquals("rgba(224, 66, 40)", element.getCssValue("border-bottom-color"));
```

Note that `border-color` is [computed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20545332/771848) and cannot be retrieved this way.

You may also [convert the rgba value to HEX format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668893/getcssvalue-color-in-hex-format-in-selenium-webdriver) to make it more readable and convenient.

---

Alternatively, you may just check if the `input` element has `error` and `input-validation-error` classes:

```
assertEquals("block error input-validation-error", element.getAttribute("class"));
```

Comment: I tried adding the code:
assertEquals("#E04228", driver.findElement(By.id("frm-Voornaam.Value")).getCssValue("border-color"));
but that resulted in:
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[#E04228]> but was:<[]>
 ......

Comment: @Hugo so, basically it's not reading the `border-color` setting at all? Are you sure the input is highlighted at the moment the assertion is made? Thanks.

Comment: this is the full CSS section: select.error,textarea.error,input[type="email"].error,input[type="number"].error,input[type="password"].error,input[type="tel"].error,input[type="text"].error,input[type="url"].error,input[type="color"].error,input[type="date"].error,input[type="datetime"].error,input[type="datetime-local"].error,input[type="month"].error,input[type="time"].error,input[type="week"].error,input[type="search"].error{
 border-color:#e04228;
 background:#fff url(../img/icon-field-error.png) no-repeat right;
 background-size:28px 22px;

Comment: and the source in the page: <input id="frm-Voornaam.Value" placeholder="Vul hier uw voornaam in" name="Voornaam.Value" class="block error input-validation-error" data-val="true" data-val-required="Het veld 'Voornaam' is verplicht" required="" type="text">

Comment: @Hugo you know what, what if we would check the presence of `error` and `input-validation-error` classes instead?..

Comment: I guess that would work too as these are the lines of codes before and after clicking 'next' without filling the mandatory fields: 
Before: <input type="text" required="" data-val-required="Het veld 'Voornaam' is verplicht" data-val="true" class="block" name="Voornaam.Value" placeholder="Vul hier uw voornaam in" id="frm-Voornaam.Value">
After: <input type="text" required="" data-val-required="Het veld 'Voornaam' is verplicht" data-val="true" class="block error input-validation-error" name="Voornaam.Value" placeholder="Vul hier uw voornaam in" id="frm-Voornaam.Value">

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, your last update worked. I had to change one thing but the code is now:

```
assertEquals("rgba(224, 66, 40, 1)", driver.findElement(By.id("frm-Voornaam.Value")).getCssValue("border-bottom-color"));
```

I had to ad [, 1] with the rgba and now it works, thank you!