# How to identify border-bottom-color in selenium webdriver

Tags: html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJSDc.jpg)My requirement is I need to verify border-bottom-color for a element present in size list the condition is when we hover to any particular size in list bottom colour changes to blue and when we click on any element colour changes to black.

I have tried using below code :

```
public void verifyBorderColour() {
        click(sizeDropDownSelector);
        List<WebElement> elements = findElements(allSizeElements);
        for (WebElement e : elements) {
            click(e);
            String rgbvalue = e.getCssValue("border-bottom-color");
            System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$rgbvalue$$$$$$$$$$$$$"+rgbvalue);

        }
    }
```

[Size Pallete with CSS RGB Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wP6X.jpg)

Comment: Please share html code for that element which u want to check bg color

Comment: So what is the println showing with your current method?

Comment: In current println I am not getting any value the output is like $$$$$$$$$$$$$$rgbvalue$$$$$$$$$$$$$

Comment: Check these thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535167/selenium-webdriver-get-border-color